# Reading from GPS-tracking Device, inputstream

Tags: java, sockets, stream, inputstream

For a new project I am using a GPS Tracking Device. This device sends every 10 seconds information to my java-server. I also created an android application. In the android application I open the connection with the server, I send the data and I close the connection again.

The problem is that the tracking device doesn't close the connection every time.

What do I have:

I have a multithreades server that starts a new thread when there is a new connection.
I can read in the information that the tracker sends me BUT only the first point, after that I doesn't receive information anymore (well, I receive it, but I cant get it displayed).

When I use the code .readLine() it works IF i shut down the tracker (and the connection. But thats not a solution, this isn't called Live Tracking

This is what I use now for the reading part

```
public Request(Socket connectionSocket) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(connectionSocket.getInetAddress().toString());
    InputStreamReader temp = new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    int read = 0;
    out = new StringBuilder();

    char[] buffer = new char[0x127];
    do {
        System.out.println("test");
        read = temp.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        System.out.println(temp.toString());
        if (read > 0) {
            out.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        System.out.println(out.toString());
        this.handleRequest(out.toString());

     } while (temp.read() != 0);


    connectionSocket.close();

    clientSentence = out.toString();
    System.out.println(out.toString());
 }
```

Could someone help me how I could read all information. The information string is ALWAYS 127 characters long.

Thanks

Wouter

Comment: If you need a length of 127, replace `char[] buffer = new char[0x127];` by `char[] buffer = new char[127];`. The 0x value is interpreted as hex, which is 295 in decimal. The buffer will never be filled if you try to read 295 bytes and send only 127 bytes so the read() waits forever.

Comment: I changed that but thats not the solution. Sorry. In fact I would have hthe connection open. The device sends 127 chars... I need those chars. 10 seconds later the device sends again.. Then. I need those chars again... So the connection has to stay open, but needs every time 127 chars..

Answer (score 0):

The while expression contains a second "read()" which tries to read an 128th character. This is blocking and gets out of sync.

I think there should be only one "read(buffer, 0, 127)" in the loop to read just 127 characters.